# Firebase Auth Password Reset: How to properly send a password reset email including the confirmation code?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I'm stuck at getting Firebase to send a password reset email including the confirmation code that's needed for the method `firebase.auth().verifyPasswordResetCode(code)`.

I'm using the `sendPasswordResetEmail(email)` method and the email includes a link which lets users create a new password.

Since I have placed some restrictions on the passwords (they must include a number), this would break the restriction.

I can't find anything in the docs on how to send the confirmation code to an email for password reset.

This is how I'm using it:

```
public sendResetPasswordEmail(email: string): Promise<any> {

  return this.fireAgent.firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email, {
    url: 'http://localhost:8100/',
    handleCodeInApp: true
  });

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Struggling with this myself. The only supplied answer doesn't work as the "URL" inside the `actionCodeSettings ` object is for the URL that you will navigate to after resetting the password through firebase.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, Firebase Authentication doesn't allow you to specify the kind of password that the user can insert on the url that the reset-password email provides you. But, you should be able to achieve it using the verification code authentication service.

To use the verification code, you need to add an object `ActionCodeSetting` to your `sendPasswordResetEmail` method. It should look like this:

```
var actionCodeSettings = {
  // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
  // URL must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
  url: 'https://www.example.com/finishSignUp?cartId=1234',
  // This must be true.
  handleCodeInApp: true,
  iOS: {
    bundleId: 'com.example.ios'
  },
  android: {
    packageName: 'com.example.android',
    installApp: true,
    minimumVersion: '12'
  }
};
```

On your case the only thing that interest your is `handleCodeInApp`. In that way the email will provide you with a code that you will need to put by hand on `verifyPasswordResetCode`.

After this, you can put the new password by hand in your client, without use Firebase email provider. Just call `confirmPasswordReset("verificationCode", "newPassword")` after check that the verification code is valid with `verifyPasswordResetCode`.

Hope that this will help you!

Comment: I tried using the `handleCodeInApp` on the `ActionCodeSetting`, but the email still only shows a link that handles creating a new password by Firebase. It doesn't contain the code that I need for `verifyPasswordResetCode` method. I've updated my question to include the current code I'm using. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you added `https://yours.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=<action>&oobCode=<code>` to your email template to add the code? You can your template to just show whatever you need:
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714?hl=en

Comment: The template is unedited and includes `%LINK%` which will be replaced with the generated link. However, I still don't see any verification code that the user can enter in my app to be verified, and the link inside the email will redirect to the new password page provided by Firebase (I also have `iOS` and `android` set correctly in my `ActionCodeSetting`).